# identity Server 4 alternate logout redirect uri

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

We are using Identity Server 4 to secure a web application and API. This part of the process is working, users are able to login and have access to various parts of the application. The issue that I am running into is during the logout process I need to pass a value to the Identity Server for one of two reasons. Either the logout happened because the user clicked the logout button (default flow) or the user was inactive for X minutes (custom process).

I have spent some extensive time reading and looking at the Identity Server 4 documentation, and it seems that while they point out that it is possible, there isn't an example. I have tried searching on how to pass/send a value during the Identity Server 4 logout and have not been able to find an answer. Many results talk about setting the RedirectUri on an AuthenticationProperties object and adding that to the `HttpContext.SignOutAsync()` method. I have done so and have not seen the PostLogoutRedirectUri of the LogoutContext change. I have made sure that I have added the 2 versions of the url (default and custom process) to clients list of RedirectUris.

Can anyone point me to what I am doing incorrect?

**UPDATE:**

We are using ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 for the client and Identity Server 4 v2.3.2 for the authority.

Signing out and revoking tokens works as it should with `HttpContext.SignOutAsync()` - the issue is that on the client there are two options the user can click the logout button firing the Logout action or a script fires the Logout action sending in a value. I need to be able to perform the normal logout process and end up displaying 1 of 2 different messages based on how the logout was initiated.

**UPDATE2:**

Since I have posted this, I have done some work with a clean project - I now know that the `LocalRedirect()` won't work for me since the hosts are different between authority and client. i.e.: Client - https://client.company.com, Authority: https://auth.company.com.

Authority

```
 public async Task Logout(string logoutid)
        {

            var logoutContext = _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutid);
            var postLogOutRedirectUri = logoutContext.Result.PostLogoutRedirectUri;


            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();


            LocalRedirect(postLogOutRedirectUri);

        }
```

MVC client

```
public async Task Logout(string value = null)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");

            //custom logout process
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {

                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    RedirectUri = $"{_config["IdentityServer:MvcClient"]}/{RedirectToAction().UrlHelper.Action("Idle", "Home")}"
                };

                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc", authProperties);

                return;
            }

            //default logout process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to specify which platforms you're using (MVC, RazorPages, Angular/WebAPI etc) so the community can help you out. After that, try detailing out what you want to do with your session expiry/log out information as there maybe alternatives to help you solve your issue. Good Luck!

Comment: As long as I know, for logout you just need to revoke your tokens, if you are using JWT token, then just revoke refresh token, if your access token has a short life, no issue. If you use reference token, you need to revoke both tokens on logout.